# mongoose return undefined when using model.find() to console log a specific property of an item inside database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a data inside my collection users with the properties username: "test", password: "password123". I want to console log only the username of this collection. Everytime I do that with console.log(user.username); it logs undefined. When I console.log(user); it works fine by showing the both the _id, username, and password.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", {
useUnifiedTopology: true,
useNewUrlParser: true,
});

const userSchema = {
username: String,
password: String,
};

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

const user = new User({
username: "test3",
password: "password123",
});

User.find(function (err, user) {
console.log(user.username);
});
```

Comment: It should be `user[0].username`

Comment: Oh.... Thank you